# Securities Law: Schedule 13G pursuant to Rule 13d-1(d) under Section 13(d)(6)(B)

Tags: united-states

Schedule 13G/Rule 13d-1(d)/Section 13(d)(6)(B) May an officer and director continue to file a Schedule 13G pursuant to Rule 13d-1(d), instead of a Schedule 13D, if (i) it has been more than 12 months since the effective date of the Form 10 (for example 3 years from the effective date) and (ii) since the effective date, such officer and director has not acquired securities, together with all other acquisitions in any 12 month period, that exceeds 2% of the class?

Said another way, for the purposes of filing a Schedule 13G pursuant to Rule 13d-1(d), is the exemption under Section 13(d)(6)(B) available to an officer and director indefinitely so long as the officer and director does not acquire securities, together with all other acquisitions in any 12 month period, that exceeds 2% of the class?

Thank you!